# How can I match a variable in an array and append the match with a number and add it to the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on an application that has users choose a name. They are already assigned a temporary name (which will never match) until they change it, usually right away.

I want it so when a user connects, if the name they've chosen is already taken then their name is appended with _# and added to the users list.

for example: 'John' is in the users list. Someone connects and they choose the name 'John'. Their name is turned into 'John_1' and they are added to the users list. If another 'John' joins then their name is 'John_2' etc.

Right now they can all have the same name. I've tried too long and it's time to ask the question, because I can't find the answer anywhere. I'm new to JavaScript and coding altogether so explanations would be amazing if someone want's to take the time.

Thank you.

Comment: it's in my repository, chat_app, my only one. I haven't really started this function yet because I've no clue where to start besides RegEx, and It's been confusing me for days

Comment: https://github.com/supafiya/chat_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count the names list with a `reduce()` and a regular expression that matches the names followed by an optional `_` and digit(s). With that info, you can build a new name an `push()` it:

```js
let names = ['John', 'Mark', 'Steve', 'John_1', 'Johnny']

function addName(newName, names){
    let re = new RegExp(`^${newName}(_\\d+)?$`)
    let matches = names.reduce((count, name) => name.match(re) ? count+1 : count, 0)
    let fixedName = matches ? newName+'_'+matches : newName
    names.push(fixedName) 
    return fixedName
}

addName("John", names)
addName("Jennifer", names)
addName("Jennifer", names)
addName("Tom", names)
addName("Tommy", names)

let newName = addName("Jennifer", names)
console.log(names)
console.log("added:", newName)
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! I was struggling very hard with RegEx

Comment: They are all being saves the the `names` list. If you want to return the new name you can return the newly created name form the function. See edited answer.

Comment: Actually it has a bug, when I go to join again, say there are 3 user in the room: user, user_1, and user_2, if I join a fourth, it will be user_2, until i go to try to change the name to user again, THEN it will be user_3. my code is all on my profile under chat_app that I'm making to learn better

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce that @supafiya. If I change the above code to start with `user, user_1, user_2` the next name that gets added is `user_3`. The example in the code has an identical case to what you describe with the name `John`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain well, these are the steps: Join as Jeff, Join as Jeff again, Join as Jeff again. You have Jeff, Jeff_1, and Jeff_2. Leave as Jeff_1, rejoin as Jeff and you have two Jeff_2

Comment: https://github.com/supafiya/chat_app/blob/master/server/server.js is my code. on line 80 is where it starts

Comment: Oh, I see. That's a different problem altogether. You are going to have to figure out what you want to happen in that case -- new Jeff_1, a Jeff_3? -- and then figure out where the last number is.  Maybe a simple array isn't the best way to store the users -- maybe an object with keys as names and arrays holding users.

Comment: My users are held by a class I made called Users. https://github.com/supafiya/chat_app/blob/master/server/users.js is the code for that. I get the userlist from a method inside the class.

Comment: would you mind telling me what the actual problem is with this? I can't figure this out.